# How do I get and display the count of each word from an object?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get and display the count of each word in the string?

I am able to sort the words from most frequent, but I cannot display the count. The object: frequencies originally displayed the count (key).

I understand that Object.keys and the map() method may help me, but I am unsure how to include it the map method in my code.

Any help is much appreciated...

```
var stringtest = "Example: This is a string. I've excluded stopwords from becoming most frequent words. This is a string of words.";
    function getFreq(string, cutOff){
      var refineStr = string.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"").toLowerCase().replace(/ to\b| is\b| for\b| you\b| the\b|your\b|an\b| on\b| by\b|this\b|will\b| of\b| a\b/g, ""),
          words = refineStr.split(" "),
          frequencies = {},
          word, frequency, i;
      for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        word = words[i];
        frequencies[" " + words[i]] = (frequencies[" " + words[i]] || 0) + 1;
        //frequencies[word]++;
      }
      words = Object.keys(frequencies);
         return words.sort(function (a,b)
          {
            return frequencies[b] - frequencies[a];}).slice(0, cutOff).toString();
    }
    document.getElementById("wordlist").innerHTML = getFreq(stringtest, 20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would personally do differently. It would probably be easier to both read and update if you keep your exclusions in a separate array. Additionally, you don't need to regex for them, you can simply use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
As for printing the results, a simple [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop will do.

```js
const write = msg => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML = msg;
};

const input = "Example: This is a string. I've excluded stopwords from becoming most frequent words. This is a string of words.";
const exclude = ["to", "is", "for", "you", "the", "your", "an", "on", "by", "this", "will", "of", "a"];

const lowerAlphaNum = input.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "").toLowerCase();
const filtered = lowerAlphaNum.split(" ").filter(word => exclude.indexOf(word) === -1);
const frequencies = {};
filtered.forEach(word => {
  frequencies[word] = (frequencies[word] || 0) + 1;
});

const sortedArr = Object.keys(frequencies).map(word => ({
  word: word,
  frequency: frequencies[word]
})).sort((a, b) => b.frequency - a.frequency);
const trimmedArr = sortedArr.slice(0, 5);

trimmedArr.forEach(item => {
  write(item.word + ': ' + item.frequency);
});
```

Comment: This is great, but I need to still sort them, i.e. most frequent at the top. I also had a cutOff to only display 20. I'm trying to figure it out with your improvements. Any clue?

Comment: @GrahamO'Mahony In that case you'd want a slightly different data structure, I've updated the above fiddle with an example of one possible solution.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much for your help. Any chance you can explain the following code to me, please?

`const sortedArr = Object.keys(frequencies).map(word => ({ word: word,    frequency: frequencies[word] })).sort((a, b) => b.frequency - a.frequency);`

I understand the sort method, as I created a similar one. Not sure about the map method. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using some code from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906807/word-frequency-in-javascript):

```js
var stringtest =
  "Example: This is a string. I've excluded stopwords from becoming most frequent words. This is a string of words.";

function stringCount(string) {
  var pattern = /(?=\S*['-])([a-zA-Z'-]+)|\w+/g,
    matchedWords = string.match(pattern);

  var counts = matchedWords.reduce(function(stats, word) {
    if (stats.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
      stats[word] = stats[word] + 1;
    } else {
      stats[word] = 1;
    }
    return stats;
  }, {});

  Object.keys(counts).map(function(key, index) {
    document.getElementById("wordlist").innerHTML +=
      `<tr>
       <td>${key}</td>
       <td>${counts[key]}</td>
     </tr>`;
  });
}

stringCount(stringtest);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
      <table class='table table-striped'>
        <thead class='thead-inverse'>
          <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="wordlist"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";

let test = 'Example: This is a string. I\'ve excluded stop words from becoming most frequent words. This is a string of words.';
test = test.replace(/[.,:]/g, '');
test = test.replace(/ to\b| is\b| for\b| you\b| the\b|your\b|an\b| on\b| by\b|this\b|will\b| of\b| a\b/g, "");
test = test.split(' ');

let obj = {};

for (let i = 0, max = test.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty([test[i]])) {
        obj[test[i]] = 1;
        continue;
    }

    obj[test[i]]++;
}

displayResult(obj, 30);

function displayResult(obj, maxAmount) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let ul = document.createElement('ul');

    if (maxAmount > keys.length) {
        maxAmount = keys.length;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {

        let li = document.createElement('li');

        li.innerHTML = keys[i] + ' : ' + obj[keys[i]];
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    document.querySelector('#wordlist').appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<div id="wordlist"></div>
```