# word frequency function, how to return if there are more than 1 most used word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Below is my current wordFrequency function.

I would like this to

1. filter out the "the", "a", "an", "and" from the string.
2. if there are more than one 'mostFrequent', show all of them.

But having a hard time figuring out how to do so.
Any help?

```
export default function wordFrequency(textData) {
    const splitTextArr = textData.toLowerCase().split(" ")
    //const filterTextArr = splitTextArr.filter(word => {
    //    if (word !== "the" && "a" && "an" && "and" && "or") {

    //    }
    //})

    splitTextArr.reduce()

    let counts = {}
    let compare = 0
    let mostFrequent

    for (var i = 0, len = splitTextArr.length; i < len; i++) {
        var word = splitTextArr[i]

        if (counts[word] === undefined) {
            counts[word] = 1
        } else {
            counts[word] = counts[word] + 1
        }
        if (counts[word] > compare) {
            compare = counts[word]
            mostFrequent = splitTextArr[i]
        }
    }
    console.log("most used word", mostFrequent)
    return mostFrequent
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [word frequency in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906807/word-frequency-in-javascript)

Comment: hmm I would say not really, it has some similarities but not what I am looking for :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really really close. I think if you want to be able to return more than one highest frequently used word, you'll want to update `mostFrequent` to be an `array` rather than just a `string` like so:

```
const mostFrequent = [];
```

Update that final `if` block to the following:

```
if (counts[word] > compare) {
  compare = counts[word];
  mostFrequent = [word];
}
if (counts[word] === compare) {
  mostFrequent.push(word);
}
```

Then if you are satisfied with returning `mostFrequent` as an array in all instances, you are done. If you want to return an array only if there is a tie, something like the following at the bottom should work:

```
if (mostFrequent.length > 0) {
  return mostFrequent;
}
return mostFrequent[0];
```

Now for filtering out those words. You are close with the filtering function that is commented out. I would modify to the following:

```
const bannedWords = ['the', 'a', 'an', 'and', 'or'];
const filterTextArr = splitTextArr.filter(word => {
  return !bannedWords.includes(word);
})
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have a one extra question regarding this. I create another question because it is hard to share the code. Would you be so kind to check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958035/javascript-map-function-pass-word-items-to-a-function-to-return-html-element