# Javascript map function - pass word-items to a function to return html element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

After finding the most used words, I pass the most used word to this alterText function
too alter the word

```
export default function alterText(txtArr, mostUsedWord, firstWord, lastWord) {
    const updatedArr = txtArr.map(word => {
        if (word === mostUsedWord) {
                word = `<span class="foo">${firstWord}</span><span class="word">${word}</span><span class="bar">${lastWord}</span>`
            }
            return word
        })
        return updatedArr
}
```

but when I have more than 1 most used word, I wonder how I can alter and make sure both words get mapped?

This was my try but did not work :(

```
export default function alterText(txtArr, mostUsedWord, firstWord, lastWord) {
    const hasMoreWords = mostUsedWord.length > 1
    const updatedArr = txtArr.map(word => {
        if (word === mostUsedWord) {
            word = `<span class="foo">${firstWord}</span><span class="word">${word}</span><span class="bar">${lastWord}</span>`
            return word
        } else if (hasMoreWords) {
            const word = mostUsedWord.map(word => {
                word = `<span class="foo">${firstWord}</span><span class="word">${word}</span><span class="bar">${lastWord}</span>`
            })
            return word
        }

    })
    console.log("arr", updatedArr)
    return updatedArr
}
```

and this is how I am calling it in useEffect to show in html

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const createContent = alterText(textArr, mostUsedWord, firstWord, lastWord)
        console.log("content", createContent)
        const textDataDiv = document.getElementById("text-data")
        textDataDiv.innerHTML = createContent
        setTextAltered(true)
    }, [mostUsedWord])
```

Comment: actually I updated the 'else if' statement to this - else if (hasMoreWords) {
             word = mostUsedWord.map(wordContent => {
                 const wordResult = `<span class="foo">${firstWord}</span><span class="word">${wordContent}</span><span class="bar">${lastWord}</span>`
                 return wordResult
            })
            return word
        }

but now it only returns those 2 most used words in html and erased all

Comment: Could you explain what kind of values `firstWord` and `lastWord` are? Are they a part of the most used words? And `mostUsedWords` is an array or a string. An array would seem like the proper choice if there are multiple words.

Comment: you should use an array of most used words and check if a word is in the array

Comment: @EmielZuurbier both firstWord and lastWord is a string "foo" for first and "bar" for last. And yes, "mostUsedWords" are indeed an array!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` a value in a map function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

I would also try to avoid using the same variable name in multiple scope levels, in this case `word`. It's not terribly accurate or descriptive if you think about it and can lead to bugs. Try to think of more descriptive variable names.

```
const word = mostUsedWord.map(mostUsedWord => {
  return `<span class="foo">${firstWord}</span><span class="word">${mostUsedWord}</span><span class="bar">${lastWord}</span>`
})
```

One strategy that has helped me with these kinds of problems in the past, and to be quite honest, still helps me, is trying to split problems into component problems. Then, when something goes wrong, you have a smaller thing to work on. At this level you can open up the Javascript console in your web browser or perhaps even the Node run time to play around or test what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes good point, what I was trying to do is override the 'word' in textArray that is same as the 'most used word'. I guess I can assign it something like this?            
```
 const alteredWord = `<span class="foo">${firstWord}</span><span class="word">${word}</span><span class="bar">${lastWord}</span>`
            return word = alteredWord
```
I realise what I need is a better condition something like "hasMoreWords && //if the iterated word is same as the words in array?"